# Use Google Cloud Functions to delete element from real-time database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have two collections, grapes and food. When I delete a grape I want to find all food items associated with that grape and delete them as well and update the count of pairings. The association exists in a nested array of keys with the food item.

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database with Ionic 5 and Google Cloud Functions. I have other working functions so I've ruled out issues with the deploy and the environment.

Data structure looks like this:

[image: Example grape]
[image]

My cloud function deploys without error, but doesn't appear to fire when I delete a grape from the client. The grape does not get deleted from any pairings.

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Other working functions

exports.deleteGrapePairings = functions.database.ref('grapes/{grapeid}').onDelete(async (snap) => {
    const grpRef = snap.ref;
    const collectionRef = functions.database.ref('grapes/' + grpRef + '/pairings');
    return collectionRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            const key = childSnapshot.key;
            functions.database.ref('pairings/' + key + '/grapes/' + grpRef).remove();
            resetPairingCount(key);
        });
    });
});

function resetPairingCount(key){
    const counterRef = functions.database.ref('/pairings/' + key + '/pairingcount');
    const collectionRef = functions.database.ref('/pairings/' + key + '/grapes');

    const messagesData = collectionRef.once('value');
    return counterRef.set(messagesData.numChildren());
}
```

How can I delete the grape from its related pairings and update the pairing count using a cloud function?

Comment: What **exactly** are you doing to delete the node that should trigger the function?  How are you observing that it doesn't get triggered?  Have you tried adding debug logging to make sure everything is as you expect?

Comment: Click a button > Alert: are you sure.. > calls service that executes: this.grapeRef = this.db.object('/grapes/' + id);
    this.grapeRef.remove(); <-- I'm expecting the cloud function to detect this and execute the code within it. I'm manually checking the db to see that its not being deleted. I haven't added debug logging to the cloud functions. Will need to figure that out

Comment: Is it possible that because I'm deleting the grape first, it can't iterate over the nested pairings?